# Visualize GELF log messages using Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grafana, gelf

**Setup**:

I have a data source which logs GELF formatted messages to logstash. Logstash is then feeding ElasticSearch the logs. Furthermore, I would like to visualize the logs within a Grafana instance.

The logstash.conf looks like follows:

```
input {
  gelf {
    use_tcp => true
    port_tcp => 12201
  }
}
 
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"] }
}
```

**Situation**:

I see the log messages listed in Grafana, but it seems that the whole HTTP message (which also holds the GELF string) is stored within the field "message".
[image]

**Problem**:

As far as I know, I cannot parse the attributes stored within the message string (for example the "International" attribute) using Grafana. Do I have to use the Gelf plugin for Logstash to parse the GELF message out of the message string? How can this be done? The goal is to visualize the attributes from the GELF message.

Comment: Have you considered using GROK pattern to parse the message?

Comment: Yes I have, but it seems a bit complicated for what I want to achieve. What do you suggest I will have to do in GROK in order to solve my problem?

Comment: In order to achieve what you want - you'll need to parse your message into its own fields. GROK is one way of doing that.

Comment: I am sending the GELF messages to logstash via HTTP Client. Is this why the HTTP header shows up in the message field? Do I have to apply changes to my logstash.conf file - maybe add an input http plugin or something like that?

Comment: yes, i know. But if I am sending a correct JSON formatted string, shouldn't be logstash capable of parsing it on its own without providing a GROK filter?

Comment: I believe logstash is failing to parse the message because the HTTP header and backslashes + a few \r\n are in the string which doesn't apply to the JSON-conformity

Comment: What if you change the output from Elasticsearch to stdout? Show how the raw message looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231066/discussion-between-user7335295-and-evaldas-buinauskas).